# ALE Code Action for python

Tags: vimrc, lsp, filetype-python, python, plugin-ale

I have a working linter with the ALE plugin.

```
Plugin 'dense-analysis/ale'

let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0
let g:ale_python_flake8_options = '--extend-ignore=E501'
nnoremap <leader>ar :ALERename<CR>
let g:ale_linters = {
    \   'python': ['pylsp'],
    \}
```

However, I cannot get the `:ALECodeAction` command to work. I get a "No code actions received from server" error.

I'm hoping to get some quick fix suggestions like in vscode.

[image: vscode code actions]

Comment: I suspect that there are no fix for Python supported.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a Vim plugin that provide fix for warning detected by the linter.

But for automatic correction of missing Python import you could be interested by [autoimport](https://lyz-code.github.io/autoimport/)

You can fix the import problem using the following Vim command:

```
:!autoimport %
```

Comment: Thank you. autoimport and many other fixers work well with the `:ALEFix` command. But similar to your example they apply it on the entire buffer/file. I'm interested in inline suggestions that let me pick between fixes that are relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm not aware of a Vim solution for that need.

Answer (score 1):

For Rust it seems that the language server propose fix that can be leverage by the [light-bulb](https://github.com/kosayoda/nvim-lightbulb) plugin.

But for Python it seems that [pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) provide warning but no suggestion fix that can be leveraged by [light-bulb](https://github.com/kosayoda/nvim-lightbulb)